# Core Bluetooth iOS - retrieving false peripherals

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth

I'm making an iOS app that uses Core Bluetooth and periodically checks to see if the peripherals are still around. My problem is that when I shut off the advertising device (even shut off the bluetooth entirely), my central device still returns the CBPeripheral object when I call retrievePeripheralsWithIdentifiers. I need it to accurately NOT return this the peripheral once it is no longer advertising. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`retrievePeripheralsWithIdentifiers` looks into the Core Bluetooth database to see if it can find an peripheral with the specified identifier, regardless of whether advertisements from that peripheral are currently visible.  This allows you to issue a connect to a peripheral that has been seen before and may be seen again (The "lock" scenario described in the Core Bluetooth Programming Guide is one example where you could use this).

To see if a peripheral is advertising or not you need to call `scanForPeripheralsWithServices`, specifying `YES` for `CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey` and keep your own table of visible peripherals, ageing them out when you haven't seen an advertisement for some period.

Comment: I've been using `scanForPeripheralsWithServices` and allowing duplicates to get my list of peripherals. However, I don't want to maintain a connection with all of them, I only want to see if they are still within range. Even if I made a table of "visible" peripherals, how would I know if each is actually still "visible"? Attempting to connect to a peripheral that is no longer within range will only result in a "connecting" state that does not time out. Is there no way to refresh the CB cache, or tell if a device is still within range?

Comment: That is why you need to allow duplicates. Set up a dictionary that stores an NSNumber (count) for each peripheral identifier you see. When you get an advertisement from a peripheral set its "count" to, say, 10. Every 30 seconds decrement all of the counts. If a count is 0 remove it from the dictionary.  You can tune the refresh time and counts to get  the desired behaviour

Comment: how could I reset Core bluetooth database?

Comment: As far as I know, the only way to do this manually is to reset network settings in the device.